# How to run functions in the background in Xamarin.Form Mobile App without stopping it when move to another PageView?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Form Mobile App, is there anyway we can run functions in the background without stopping it when we move to another PageView?
For example, I want to run this below C# code in my App for listening to Firebase Real-Time Database without stopping it when I move to another PageView to keep my data update nicely without having to start it again which will delay/slow my UI process:

```
var firebase = new FirebaseClient("");
var observable = firebase
.Child("RoomInfo")
.AsObservable<RoomModel>()
.Subscribe(d => getTotalMember = d.Object.TotalMember);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use asynchronous function using `async` and `await` keywords. It will run your function, and allow other processes to continue before your function will return value.
See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

The exact implementation depends on the rest of your code and how you will structure it, but the concept should get you on the right track.

If it is bigger task, you can run it using `Task.Run`, which will execute your code independently from main thread (note: to update values on UI you will have to use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, as `Task.Run` will change thread your code is executed on, while UI will be still executed on the main thread).

Comment: i am working on this and will let you know if i face any erros!

Comment: For detailed background task solution you can refer to :https://stackoverflow.com/a/49543446/8187800.

Comment: the solution made my code works as i want now. appreciated that

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT appreciated that. i will check it out.